# Github Wiki Pages: Is there a way to modify the Pages menu?

Tags: github, markdown, wiki, gollum-wiki

I'm using Github Wiki Pages to document my private repository. By default, Github displays a `Pages` sidebar with a search box and a list of all pages:

[image: Screenshot of Wiki Pages sidebar menu]

I have created custom sidebar menus using `_Sidebar.md` and would love to remove the `Pages` menu, but somehow keep the search box if possible.

Does anyone know if Github supports this?

The `Pages` menu doesn't seem to be a feature of [Gollum](https://github.com/gollum/gollum/wiki), the library that Github uses to create the Wiki...but if it is, is there a way of modifying it?

Comment: I don't see any options for that. I just keep the default sidebar closed in that case. You should try GitHub support.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There isn't a feature to:

> remove the Pages menu, but somehow keep the search box

If this changes I'll post an update.

Comment: Someone from GitHub Support confirmed this as well, responding to my question on Twitter: https://twitter.com/GitHubHelp/status/627210628403470336